# Bootstrap 3 center image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am trying to put image always at middle and center in some element, only problem is that it does not work

Here is my code

**CSS**

```
.panel - empty {
        width: 100 % ;
        height: 400 px; /* for demo only */
    }
    .panel-empty-inside {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .box-inside {

        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

And **HTML**

```
   <div class="panel-empty">
                <div class="panel-empty-inside">
                    <div class="box-inside">
                        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.gusonthego.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Gus-Flying-Banner-Hello-nBG.png" alt="Banner"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9395/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using class **img-responsive** which adds `display:block` to your image and can't be centered using `text-align:center`. You can center block elements of known width with `margin:0 auto`. Take a look at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9397/

Answer (score 0):

You must to put a height in the parent of the image.

```
.panel-empty-inside {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 400px;
}
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the height and width in .panel-empty class and remove the display:table-cell,text-align:center in .panel-empty-inside class then run and it is work.

```
    .panel-empty{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .panel-empty-inside {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .box-inside {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add display: table to the container with display:table-cell

Over here, you need to add

```
.panel-empty {
display:table;
}
```